# The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns. I am unable to get multiple data sets in my entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I got this message:

[image]

Please help me solve this

```
public virtual int SP_GetPendingRequset_Example(Nullable<int> pageNbr, Nullable<int> pageRow, Nullable<int> user_Id, string empCode)
{
    var pageNbrParameter = pageNbr.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("PageNbr", pageNbr) :
            new ObjectParameter("PageNbr", typeof(int));

    var pageRowParameter = pageRow.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("pageRow", pageRow) :
            new ObjectParameter("pageRow", typeof(int));

    var user_IdParameter = user_Id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("User_Id", user_Id) :
            new ObjectParameter("User_Id", typeof(int));

    var empCodeParameter = empCode != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("EmpCode", empCode) :
            new ObjectParameter("EmpCode", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SP_GetPendingRequset_Example", pageNbrParameter, pageRowParameter, user_IdParameter, empCodeParameter);
}
```

I have an `Int` in a complex result not return and result.

Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: Returning an int sounds pretty scalar to me and rather not complex.

Comment: asp.net and angularjs aren't involved here right?

Comment: Change int to object. Also remove : (IObjectContextAdapter)

Comment: jdweng - i cant not manual int to object it autometic create with update sp in EntityDB .

Comment: what does the sproc look like?